# configure Gmail accounts to send notifications for mailbox updates to a topic

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-pubsub, google-workspace

I am new to gsuite application.
I am trying to push any new email that comes to Gmail I want to push to a topic.
Here is the link i am following:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#protocol
To configure Gmail accounts to send notifications to your Cloud Pub/Sub topic, simply use your Gmail API client to call watch() on the Gmail user mailbox similar to any other Gmail API call.

I was not sure how it can be achieved? any sample running code will be great.do we need to write python scipt or do we need to write cloudfunction to configure, please advise?

Answer (score 2):

[This tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/intelligent-gmail-processing/index.html) may be a good place to start: it walks you through the steps of enabling the Gmail API, authorizing access, and setting up Cloud Functions for watching for messages and processing incoming messages. The tutorial is in JavaScript, not Python, but it should give you a good idea of an architecture that can accomplish what you're interested in.

As for Python-specific resources: the [Gmail API Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) is a good place to get started making Gmail API calls. Once you have that working, you can try switching it to call watch().

Note that if you want to continue to get notifications on your Cloud Pub/Sub topic, you will need to [call watch() at least every 7 days](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#renewing_mailbox_watch). One way to achieve this could be to use [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart) to periodically trigger a Cloud Pub/Sub topic that in turn triggers a Cloud Function, which calls watch().